# Rails rspec test wheter controller action define instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, rspec, controller, instance

I have a controller with action:

```
def new
  @team = Team.new
  @team.team_links.build
end
```

And I want to test this action with rspec. (I know it works, because it works as it should in the application, but my specs are failing.) Here is my spec:

```
it "returns new team with built in team_link" do
  get 'new'

  team = assigns(:team)
  team.should be_new_record
  team.team_links.should_not be_empty # HERE IS WHERE IT FAILS
end
```

Here is the error message:

```
 1) TeamsController GET new returns @team and builds one team_link
     Failure/Error: team.team_links.should_not be_empty
       expected empty? to return false, got true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@team.team_links.build` is neither a persist record nor an instance variable, so the effect of this line disappeared in view context.

You need to assign it as an instance variable to be testable in view:

```
# Controller
@team_link = @team.team_link.build

# Rspec
assigns(:team_link).should_not be_empty
```